# Why isn't there HMAC authentication bundle?

Tags: symfony

There are few Symfony2 WSSE bundles available, but I can't find HMAC one.

I'm confused as this type of authentication is one of the best, plus it's used by `AWS` which is the leader of Cloud Computing.

Why isn't HMAC authentication bundle there?

Answer (score 1):

We've just released a HMAC bundle (https://github.com/seigyo/SeigyoHmacBundle). It's still in development, but worth a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this bundle will be good for you. I think this is implemented what you are looking for:

https://packagist.org/packages/mardy-git/hmac

Comment: This is not Symfony bundle.